# filter the given data and calculate the sum of their amount in r

Tags: r

FILTER THE CUSTOMER_NO ONLY IF THEY sub on 01-07-2018 and renewal on 02-07-2018 and if this condition matches, then sum their corresponding amount

```
       DATE CUSTOMER_NO  SUB_PACK  RESULT AMOUNT
1: 01-07-2018   987456321   SUB STF     sub    1.0
2: 02-07-2018   987456321   SUB STF renewal    1.0
3: 01-07-2018   963852741   SUB URU     sub    0.5
4: 02-07-2018   951263847   SUB URU renewal    1.0
5: 01-07-2018   789654123 SUB TUTOR     sub    0.5
6: 02-07-2018   789654123 SUB TUTOR renewal    1.0
7: 02-07-2018   965231487   SUB BAK renewal    5.0
8: 02-07-2018   859632147   SUB PAK renewal    3.0
```

pls help me out and give the exact solution for this query..Thanks in advance

Comment: Your data is not in a usable format. Can you `dput` your data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```
df <- data.frame(
    date   = c("01-07-2018", "02-07-2018", "01-07-2018", "02-07-2018", "01-07-2018", "02-07-2018", "02-07-2018", "02-07-2018"), 
    custno = c(987456321, 987456321, 963852741, 951263847, 789654123, 789654123, 965231487, 859632147),
    result = c("sub", "renewal", "sub", "renewal", "sub", "renewal", "renewal", "renewal"),
    amount = c(1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 5, 3)
)

subs   <- df[df$date == "01-07-2018" & df$result == "sub",     "custno"]
renews <- df[df$date == "02-07-2018" & df$result == "renewal", "custno"]
important <- subs[subs %in% renews]
sum(df[df$custno %in% important, "amount"])
```

Data Table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[ , cond1 := sum(date == "01-07-2018" & result == "sub") > 0, by=custno]
dt[ , cond2 := sum(date == "02-07-2018" & result == "renewal") > 0, by=custno]
dt[cond1 == 1 & cond2 == 1, .(result = sum(amount)), by=custno]
```

Comment: df<-read.csv("sample.csv")
df
names(df)
sub_custnos   <- df[DATE == "01-07-2018" & RESULT == "sub",     "CUSTOMER_NO"]
renew_custnos <- df[DATE == "02-07-2018" & RESULT == "renewal", "CUSTOMER_NO"]

result <- sub_custnos[sub_custnos %in% renew_custnos]                  
 Error in `[.data.frame`(df, DATE == "01-07-2018" & RESULT == "sub", "CUSTOMER_NO") : 
  object 'DATE' not found

Comment: You will have to use `df$DATE` and `df$RESULT` and so on.

Comment: Sorry guys - edits made.  I always miss something when I write code directly in SO instead of in R first (which is something I tend to do when the OP doesn't provide a ready-to-use dataset).

Comment: actually this a big dataset ... here I consider it as a sample one ... so I can't take this data frames .

Comment: @Dan Y- Thank you so much.